# Where are Crystal Pieces for the Dreams In Oblivion quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

For the Falskaar quest *Dreams in Oblivion*, where are the four crystal pieces located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One is found in the Priory, in Vernan's hideout. *Given to Brother Arnand and does not count towards the quest!*

Another one is found as part of *No harm, No foul*, a quest given by Kunnari in Amber Creek.

3rd piece can be found as part of *Runaway Cattle*, a quest given by Audmund at Audmund's farm, south of Amber Creek on the other side of the mountain.

4th piece can be found as part of *Dread Aura*, a quest given by Klara in Amber Creek Inn.

Last piece can be found as part of *Deadliest Catch*, a quest given by Galen at Falskaar Docks.

Comment: Fourth is in Riverwatch hot springs (cave below the springs), mission: Dread aura (from Klara in Amber Hold Inn).

Comment: Yes, thank you @user53147. I'm not sure that the first one counts towards the quest, though.

Comment: @One-One I don't know how to get inside, but I used tcl (toggle no collision) and checked that there was *no* crystal there. I can't find the last one for the quest - with or without console.

Comment: I can confirm that one of the crystal pieces is in Sandyshell Hollow (the cave west of the docks). You get a quest from the kid in the Falskaar Docks that sends you in there to investigate. Thanks for the other two! Great questline.  
  
@One-One Volkrund Keep is only accessible later in this quest. You'll know when.