# Who gives the quest leading to Volkrund Keep in Falskaar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

I'm looking for the last crystal piece and it's supposed to be in Volkrund Keep, but I can't get in (even if my follower opens uses the lever there's another closed door). Who gives the quest connected to that place or is there a way to complete Dreams In Oblivion without it?

Comment: There is no crystal piece in Volkrund Keep. In [another question I answered](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126449/where-are-crystal-pieces-for-the-dreams-in-oblivion-quest), I was under the same impression, however, I found out that the last piece was inside Vernan's journal. (The answer there is now updated.)